# combine unix command on exec

Tags: php, unix, exec, cp

I use `exec()` to execute this a `cp` UNIX command:

```
  $path = "/var/www/copy_dir/";
  $pp = "cp -R /var/www/top_folder/mid_folder/base_folder/".$user_id."/* ".$path;
  exec($pp, $ax, $ay);
  if($ay === 0) {
    return "done";
  } else {
    return "error";
    exit;
  }
```

This works fine, it does what I need, however, I want to execute `rm -rf` (or other more safer way to clear the contents of the dir) on the `$path` first before copying. Can I combine it on my current `$pp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use a semicolon if you want to unconditionally execute both commands. Or (as mentioned by g13n) double ampersand, which will only execute the second command if the first one succeeds.

```
$path = "/var/www/copy_dir/";
$pp = "rm -rf '$path*' && cp -R /var/www/top_folder/mid_folder/base_folder/".$user_id."/* ".$path;
exec($pp, $ax, $ay);
if($ay === 0) {
    return "done";
} else {
    return "error";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can't get the status code of the first command, afaik

Comment: You could either use `;` or `&&` which means if `rm(1)` is successful then `cp(1)`.  Also, be sure to use `escapeshellarg()` to filter out any malicious input.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean clear the dir first?

```
$pp = "rm -rf $path && cp -R /var/www/top_folder/mid_folder/base_folder/$user_id/* $path";
```